Incorrect Spacing with Equals Sign and Transpose in ConTeXt
I am experiencing an issue with spacing in ConTeXt when using the equals sign in conjunction with the \transpose function. Specifically, when I input = \transpose A A, the space that should appear between = and \transpose A is instead appearing between \transpose A and A.
The \transpose function is defined in math-def.mkxl as \definemathfunction[transpose][right=\transposesymbol]. So the same spacing issue occurs when I replace \transpose with other functions like \adjoint or \derivative, or when I substitute the equals sign = with symbols like \sim or \leq.
We can even consider the following simplified MWE.
\definemathfunction[rightB][right=B]
\definemathfunction[leftB][left=B]
\startTEXpage[offset=5pt]
  \m{- \rightB A A} \\
  \m{= \rightB A A} \\
  \m{= \leftB A A}
\stopTEXpage

On my local setup (TeX Live, ConTeXt version: 2024.02.27), the output is as follows.

However, when I run the same code on context-on-web.eu, the output is as expected.

This leads me to suspect that somewhere in TeX Live there may be a problem with the right and the left option in \definemathfunction.
Could anyone help me understand and resolve this spacing issue? Thank you!

Seems like a(nother) problem that got fixed after the TL release. Will be fixed in next TL automatically. I suggest that you use the standalone if you need the latest. That is also where fixes will be done. Fixing specific issues in the TL version will only risk implementing other ones.

I temporarily solved the problem with = \phantom{} \transpose A A.
